# Why can't the touch layer on the screen can't be replaced?

Tags: touchscreen, broken-screen, touch

AFAIK, touchscreen has three different layers: the protective glass, the touch panel, and the LCD screen:

[image]
<sub>[Touch technology in smartphones explained - FlatpanelsHD](https://www.flatpanelshd.com/focus.php?subaction=showfull&id=1348049303)</sub>

However, when an area of the screen is not responsive, in my observation technicians will replace the whole screen, not just the touch panel, and this would increase the fixing cost significantly. Why is that?

Comment: Digitiser and screen are normally sold together and they are likewise changed together unless you insist and they accommodate. More revenue to them

Comment: What is the "digitiser"? There is no appropriate [meaning in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitizer_(disambiguation)). Is it the touch panel in the above image?

Comment: [see this](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/219568/How+does+the+digitizer+work). BTW your question is off topic being Android independent (most touch screens work the same way and nothing specific to Android)

Comment: You do see the "adhesive" in the middle right? Most screens right now are in some way laminated (especially AMOLEDs), glued together by optical adhesives, which most shops either can't separate or can't guarantee to apply back without compromising display performance or structural integrity.

Comment: @AndyYan if a shop claims to be able to do so, would the new glue stop adhere after sometimes (the insurance time, for example)?

Comment: The glue is cured/solidified with UV light, so if it's properly applied then there's little chance it'll come apart. The problem though is usually not applying the glue properly (or using low-quality glue) in the first place, resulting in bubbles, display artifacts, etc.

Comment: @AndyYan do you know why some area of the touch panel can be dead, while the rest is not?

Comment: Not sure about that - I don't dig into the mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the phone, really. I had a Motorolla Attrix HD with a broken touchscreen, the LCD was fine, and I was able to order a replacement touchscreen by itself. However, during the repair, separating the LCD screen form the touchscreen damaged the LCD (it was glued on way more tightly than the one in the youtube video I was following for this exact model).

Some phones, the touchscreen and LCD screen are sold as an assembly, other phones, the 2 parts are available separately.